# Updating existing users with User Import module

Tags: 6, users, importing-exporting

I'm trying to update user profiles using the [User Import](http://drupal.org/project/user_import) module. Under 'Update Existing Users' option, I have set profile to replace data. However, when I try to import the new profiles, I always get the error message that the users are duplicates and the new profiles do not get imported.
Is there a way round this, so that I can update user profiles with User Import?